# Catch exception in Rails and POST to a separate Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception

I am working on a dashboard app which shows the server status, site stats and more and I am looking to add Rails application exception tracking as well.

My main reason for wanting to create my own is basically because I want an integrated version which is just one page showing everything happening on my servers and apps.

The dashboard app is a Rails app which has an `app_exceptions` controller & model with the following: `app_id` `environment` `host` `message` `user_agent`.

Would it be possible to throw all exception messages (much like Airbrake, etc) to this Dashboard app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update, I am now using the rails_exception_handler gem - https://github.com/Sharagoz/rails_exception_handler

With this I can POST to my Dashboard app very easily :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the rescue_from in your application controller to call a method that POSTs to your dashboard API.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
rescue_from Exception, :with => :postNotification
```

[rescue_from info](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html)

on your :with method definition, define a variable space and you can POST that passed var to your dashboard API, you could do analyzation / display on the dashboard side to give you the most playing room as far as what exception info you want to work with:

```
def postNotification(e)
   postToDashboardAPI(e)
end
```

Comment: It's that simple? Nice. How would I be able to collect & send the parameters such as the error type, the messages, etc?

Comment: And you could post using Net::HTTP.post_form